# What is the most efficient UPDATE statement to bulk update a table column used in the WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-aurora

I have to execute the following UPDATE statement on a large table, partitioned using a timestamp field with a resolution of one day:

```sql
UPDATE my_huge_table
   SET column1 = 'an-uuid4'
 WHERE customer_id = 'a-customer-uuid4'
   AND organization_id = 'an-organization-uuid4'  
column1 IN ('another-uuid4', 'yet-another-uuid4', ...)
```

where `customer_id`, `organization_id` and `column1` columns are all properly indexed.

That statement is executed by an Aurora database (PostgreSQL) on AWS.

It turns out that, sometimes, that query times out. The reason, according to the performance insights provided by AWS, is that likely an inefficient plan is used to execute the query, as a lot of data must be read in one shot from the file system.

My guess is that the database is loading a huge amount of table records in memory as the column being updated is the same used for the selection.

I wonder whether there's a more efficient way, performance-wise, to accomplish the same task.

Comment: How large is the table and roughly how many of those records do you expect would be targeted by the update?

Comment: Are you able to do a `COUNT(*)` so you know how many records will be effected?

Comment: You didn't share the contents of performance insights.  So we have no idea what the current plan is, only that you think it could possibly be better.

Comment: Why do you have a timeout set in the first place?

Comment: @jjanes I think there's a misunderstanding. There isn't any timeout set. I just said that the query times out. Well, technically it's the connection used to execute the query that times out.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The table has currently 15,225,688 records.

Regarding your second question that query is executed for batches of 25 elements. That means the number of elements provided to the `IN` operator are up to 25.

Comment: @MintBerryCRUNCH The table has currently 15,225,688 records.

Comment: @MicheleCardone Are you able to provide the indexs? Have you used a computed index?

Comment: @jjanes What I am able to see from Performance Insights is that a relatively large portion of the time is spent in the IO:DataFileRead section (~ 20%) which, according to the description provided by AWS, may be a symptom of an inefficient query plan that requires reading a huge amount of data.

Unfortunately, for privacy reasons, the real arguments used for the query are obfuscated. I may post an explain plan obtained using random UUID's, but it may not really be representative of what is happening in production with real data.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the real table is also partitioned by a timestamp field. I'll update the post description.

Comment: @MintBerryCRUNCH All indexes are standard B-Tree indexes and are attached to each partitioned table.

Comment: Timeouts (other than possibly TCP ones) generally don't just happen, someone has to have done something to configure them.  What is the error message you get, both on the client and in the server's log?

Comment: Even if the values are obfuscated, we would still want to know if it changed from an =ANY index scan to a seq scan, or example, and if the row estimates were about correct or way off.

Comment: @jjanes Here's a link to the explain plan I was mentioning:

https://hastebin.com/raw/rewalabeja

Comment: That plan says it took less than half a second.  Is that the performance which needs improvement, or is that from a faster execution which is fast enough?

Comment: @jjanes As I previously stated, that plan is not a real plan, as I used fake UUIDs values. This query takes a lot of time in production, and very frequently times out after 500 seconds, as the latter is the connection timeout configured for our PostgreSQL Aurora instances.